# Bipartite graph in xypic

Tags: graphs, xy-pic

Could you help me somebody please. I don't understand, how I can draw bipartite graphs using `xypic`, for example K3,3 or something like that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You might want to switch to using tikz. As far as I remember there is a graph package based on tikz that includes the various standard graphs

Answer (score 2):

There are more flexible tools for doing this sort of drawing -- TikZ, TikZ-cd or Metapost for example -- and perhaps more friendly ones too.  Having said that there is [some good documentation](https://tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/Xy-pic.html) available and `xypic` is a very mature and clever tool.  Here's an example that might get you started.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xypic}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{ 
    {\bullet} \ar@{-}[r]   \ar@{-}[rd] \ar@{-}[rdd] & {\bullet} \\
    {\bullet} \ar@{-}[ru]  \ar@{-}[r]  \ar@{-}[rd]  & {\bullet} \\
    {\bullet} \ar@{-}[ruu] \ar@{-}[ru] \ar@{-}[r]   & {\bullet} 
}
\end{document}
```

The basic idea is that you lay out a matrix of nodes with the symbol you want at each node, here I've used `\bullet` to create the black blobs.  And then you use the `\ar` command to draw arrows between the nodes.  The `@{-}` part controls the style of the arrows, here the `-` gives lines with no arrow heads. The `[rrr]` bit controls the direction of the arrow: r for right, u for up, d for down (and so on).

For any more fine control you'll need to read the manual, or ask another question here about a more specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Ti*k*Z:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphs.standard}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [nodes={draw, circle}, clockwise, radius=.5cm, empty nodes, n=3] {
    subgraph I_n [name=inner] --[complete bipartite]
    subgraph I_n [name=outer]
};  
\end{tikzpicture}   
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [nodes={draw, circle}, clockwise, radius=.5cm, empty nodes, n=4] {
    subgraph I_n [name=inner] --[complete bipartite]
    subgraph I_n [name=outer]
};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [nodes={draw, circle}, clockwise, radius=.5cm, empty nodes, n=5] {
    subgraph I_n [name=inner] --[complete bipartite]
    subgraph I_n [name=outer]
};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Taken from chapter 19 of the pgfmanual.pdf

---

Or maybe you want:

```
\tikz \graph [branch right, grow down]
{ subgraph K_nm [V={6,...,8}, W={b,...,d}] };
```

or

```
\tikz \graph {
    subgraph I_nm [n=3, m=3];
    V 1 -- { W 2, W 3 };
    V 2 -- { W 1, W 3 };
    V 3 -- { W 1, W 2 };
};
```